# jQueryUI tabs mouseover a disabled link, how do I change the cursor so it doesn't appear clickable?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery ui tabs. The app correctly sets the css class to .ui-state-disabled and the link can be clicked but it doesn't do anything. What I'm trying to accomplish here is making the cursor appear as default instead of the hand/pointer.  I cannot get this to work.

css

```
.ui-state-disabled:hover {
     cursor: default;
}
```

html

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-state-disabled">
   <a href="#Procedures" title="Procedures">
       <div>Procedures</div>
   </a>
 </li>
```

Does anyone know how to correct this? I don't want the user to think the element is clickable whilst in this state.  Thanks for any tips or tricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery ui and and you want to override one of it's classes, you need to use `!important`. This way your css definition of the class will take more importance.

```
.ui-state-disabled:hover {
     cursor: default !important;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work but the idea is correct.  I ended up using a modified rule and it worked correctly. 
.ui-state-disabled:hover,  .ui-state-disabled a:hover, .ui-state-disabled a:hover div{
    cursor: default !important;
}

Comment: the answer was not working due to the anchor tag being present. You need only target the a tag as such:

`.ui-state-disabled > a { cursor: default; }`